# How to unlock the "question mark" car body and wheel styles in JellyCar Worlds?

Tags: jellycar-worlds

In [JellyCar Worlds](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1740930/JellyCar_Worlds/), the last car body and the last wheel are both labeled a single question mark. How to unlock them?

While I happened to get the secret wheel, I have no idea when and how.

[image][image]